# Are Spring beans configured using Grails' Spring Bean DSL transactional by default?

Tags: spring, grails

Services in Grails (which are Spring beans) are transactional by default, but I can also configure my own Spring beans using the Spring Bean DSL.

Are these beans also transactional by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not by default.  The services Grails plugin (one of the core plugins) explicitly creates transactional proxies for services that want to be transactional.

Comment: Any Spring bean that's annotated with @Transactional will also be wrapped in a proxy